# Ajax return error on success calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a simple form, do jquery form validation after submit, then Ajax call to form handler to send email, handler return string "success" or "error". Now when I run debugger, I saw Ajax post to the form handler, and sent out email successfully, but somehow Ajax displayed "status: error,error: Not Found"

Here's my code:

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myForm").submit(function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault();
            
        $('#myForm .required').each(function() {
            if($.trim($(this).val()) === '') {
                alert("Please fill the required field.");
                $(this).focus();
                return false;
            } 
        }); 
        
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "/mydomain/dispatcher/myFormHandler",
            data : $("#myForm").serialize(),
            dataType : "html",  
            success : function(data)  { console.log("Ajax call success");},
            error : function(request, status, error) { console.log ('status: ' + status+ ',error: ' + error);}
        });

        return false;
    });  
});
</script>
```

```css
Inside form handler Java:
    ...
    @RequestMapping(value = "/myFormHandler")
    public String myFormHandler(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
       ...
       if (email sent)
         return "success"
       else
           return "error"
    }
```

```html
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="/mydomain/dispatcher/myFormHandler">
<p>Name (required): <input type=text name="contactName" class="required" size=16 value="">
<p>Email (required): <input type=text name='contactEmail' class="required" size=16 value=""></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: generally this occurs due to mismatch between what jQuery is expecting and what server sends as response.. please make sure these two match the type. If possible post the screenshot or snippet of `myFormHandler` action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a java expert, but seems the response from the servlet is sent incorrectly, It should be something like

```
public void myFormHandler(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    if (email sent)
        json.put("success", true);
    else
        json.put("success", false);    
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
}
```

**EDIT**

if html response is the intent, something simple like this should work

```
public void myFormHandler(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    if (email sent)
        response.getWriter().write("success"); 
    else
        response.getWriter().write("error");     
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you Shakib, but in my ajax I have dataType : "html", do I still need to set json response in java?

Comment: No, in that case simply write the html content through response object

Comment: Thank you Shakib, change return "success" to response.getWriter().write("success");  solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

May be you are including the `relative` path of the file in your `AJAX` request. May be the URL is imcomplete,Thats one of the reasons this `error` may come.

Since the `AJAX` request is initiating from the browser, its not relative to any file in the server.

**NOTE:**

If you are giving relative path like

```
somedir/filename in your `url` request make sure you do not prepend it with `'/'` like
```

`/somedir/filename`

**EDIT:** I am not sure what you mean by full url,but if you type the url in the browser, it should be able to give you the response

Comment: That happened to me as well, just try including the full url in the ajax request, the error wont come

Comment: is the url in the same domain or different?

Comment: yes, same domain, both form and spring controller are on my local environment.

Comment: I tried url  "http://localhost:9080/mydomain/dispatcher/myFormHandler", Ajax still return "status: error,error: Not Found "

Comment: What is this mydomain?Is it just a folder or you specify some domain name?If its some domain name,you dont need that since you already have localhost in your url..that itself is your local domain

Comment: "mydomain" is the context root of my web project